# Button that used to post an Action and a Script in the same time in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

In a view, I have a button 'Enregistrer' which I add in it a JQuery Script.

The script is used to delete the item selected from the DropDownList 'Poste'.

This button has as purpose to save some values in a list named 'ListG'.

The problem that the button works perfectly but when i add the Script, the situation change and the button didn't works and became static (dead).

**Scenario of my issue :**

1. user selects something on the "dropdownlist"
   poste
2. user fills the form
3. user hits enregistrer
4. javascript removes the selected item from poste
5. form is submitted to the action
6. action does something
7. action return a view with lots of data
8. view is rendered, with all the options at poste again

**The problem is that I must remove the item at the action.**

Precisly :

I have 2 collections: PostesItems and ListG
I must remove from PostesItems postes that are already on ListG.

This is the code in the view :

```
<%@  Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ProfileGa")) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset class="parametrage">
        <legend>Gestion de Gamme</legend>

        <div>
        <%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPoste, Model.PostesItems, new { @id = "poste" })%>



         <div>
         <%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Nbr_Passage)%>
         </div>
         <div class="editor-field">
          <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nbr_Passage)%>
          </div>

        <div>
        <%:Html.Label("Position :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Position)%>
        </div>

        <div>
        <%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PosteSuivantSelected, Model.PostesItems, new { @id = "dd" })%>


     </div>    

     <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" id="btnSave"   />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('#btnSave').click(function () {
                $('#poste option:selected').remove();

            });
        });

    </script>
```

and this is the code of model :

```
public class FlowViewModel
    {

        [Key]
        public string IDv { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public SelectList PostesItems { get; set; }

        public List<Gamme> GaItems { get; set; }

        public string SelectedPoste { get; set; }

        public string PostePrecedentSelected { get; set; } 
        public string PosteSuivantSelected { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string  Nbr_Passage { get; set; }

         [NotMapped]
        public List<Gamme> ListG {get;set;}


    }
```

And finally the code  in the controller :

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
       {   
            var viewModel = new FlowViewModel();
            viewModel.PostesItems = new SelectList(db.Postes.ToList(), "ID_Poste", "ID_Poste");
            viewModel.Profile_GaItems = db.Profil_Gas.ToList();
            viewModel.GaItems = db.Gammes.ToList();
            viewModel.ListG = (List<Gamme>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["GammeList"];

            return View(viewModel);

        }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(FlowViewModel model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                Gamme G = new Gamme();
                G.ID_Gamme = model.SelectedProfile_Ga;
                G.ID_Poste = model.SelectedPoste;

                G.Next_Posts = model.PosteSuivantSelected;
                G.Nbr_Passage = int.Parse(model.Nbr_Passage);
                G.Position = int.Parse(model.Position);

                ((List<Gamme>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["GammeList"]).Add(G);
                var list = ((List<Gamme>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["GammeList"]);


            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
                   }
```

**Solution that I try :**

I add this line to the methode Index in the controller :

```
viewModel.PostesItems.Where(x => !viewModel.ListG.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

*But there is an error of compilation !*

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcApplication2.Models.Gamme>.Contains(MvcApplication2.Models.Gamme)' has some invalid arguments
AND Error 7 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' to 'MvcApplication2.Models.Gamme'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using linq against totally different objects

```
PostesItems is of type 'SelectList'
and ListG is of type List<Gamme>
```

How will you be able to equate them in the linq query.

Instead you should be using something like this

```
foreach(var postItem in viewModel.PostesItems){
   viewModel.ListG.ForEach((x)=>{
        if((x.PostId != postItem.Text) || (x.PostId != postItem.Value)){
           // Your logic goes here...
        }
   });
}
```

Provide more details on what you wanted to accomplish in the line that gives you the error. You are trying to check if an object list contains a selectlistitem.